# How to find timezone of a station in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: timezone, timezone-offset

I have 5000+ airport codes (with latitude, longitude) in a table and timezone list is available in a master table with these timezones: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973627.

How can I map the timezone to an airport code? For same offset we can have multiple time zones. Example: GMT-06:00 has multiple timezone names.

The mapping list available on websites do not have the same timezone names which are there in the link.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Google perhaps?

Comment: This isn't related to SQL, it has to do with timezones, offsets and the IANA database. Anyone working in the travel industry knows the pain

Comment: Whoever voted to close, please understand the question first before voting. The OP is most definitely not asking for a tutorial on SQL

Comment: @r_agg the offset list you point to is invalid anyway - it's 6 years old. There have been several changes, deployed through Windows Update

Comment: Whoever votes to close, this isn't a broad question. To anyone who has done this, it's a very specific *and* troublesome issue, because it's partly a business issue. The technical part though is very specific

Comment: @r_agg consider asking at `aviation.stackexchage.com` and `travel.stackexchange.com` as well.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something that SQL Server can do natively, you will have to map lat/lon to timezone yourself, see http://timezonedb.com/ for an opensource dataset that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE** The list of Windows Timezones for Windows XP is invalid. It has changed several times in the past, the latest only a few months ago. In any case, Windows timezone names aren't used in travel, or anywhere else for that matter.

GMT-6 isn't a timezone, it's an offset. Timezones are those found in the IANA database, eg. `Russia\Moscow`. Depending on time of year the offset changes. Actually, Russian time zones have changed many times over the last decade so you need to know the full date to calculate the offset.

The IANA database contains all timezones and the rules to calculate their offsets back to the 19th century.

Your airport reference table should contain the airport code and the timezone, resolving the offsets in client code. Storing the offsets isn't practical. Not only do they change, but there are no fixed dates to mark the change from winter to summer time.

I understand this is a bit of pain when you want to calculate travel durations. If the number of calculations isn't very large, you can do everything client-side. The IANA database isn't large and is often embedded in libraries, which means each calculation costs a few CPU cycles. Another option is to create a SQLCLR assembly to do the translation on the server. Even big travel agencies (as in Top 10 in Europe) don't need that though.

In Linux systems the [IANA timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) is part of the OS and you can resolve offsets with system calls. In Windows, you can use a library like [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) to resolve timezones to offsets.

The IANA database is updated regularly. Libraries that embed it have to be recompiled with the new data, which means you have to update whichever you use as well.

All airport reference data eg from Flightstats or other providers always contain the timezone.

If you care about airport timezones, you should avoid using `datetime` in SQL Server and use `datetimeoffset` wherever possible. Rather than assume that all travel dates are local dates (thus requiring airport lookups and conversions), be explicit. All airlines post their schedules with valid offsets anyway. This can make duration calculations *a lot* easier.

**As for matching airports to timezones**

This process can't be fully automated, because all datasets (even commercial offerings) have omissions. Even if you buy a commercial service, there will be cases where the airport is missing and you have to google for it by city name etc. This can happen for example if an airport hasn't opened yet but airlines have started selling flights from/to it.

Matching coordinates to timezones isn't very helpful. It's easier to match the airport codes themselves. There are several services that offer web service or REST endpoints which you can call to request airport information. Understandably, the free/open source services are less reliable than the commercial offerings.

As a starting point, you should find some services, query them for the airports you already have and keep the information, updating it whenever a new airport comes up. Expect to spend some time cleaning up the data though.

Consider subscribing to a commercial service - they have adopted a per-use model that costs very little if you only have 5000 calls to make. They also provide a lot of information like coordinates, locations, performance informations etc.